# Compilation Error with NSParameterAssert with Xcode 6.3

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6.3

I am getting compilation errors anywhere NSParameterAssert is used. For example:

```
-(instancetype)initForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot withFunction:(CPTDataSourceFunction)function
{
    NSParameterAssert([plot isKindOfClass:[CPTScatterPlot class]]);
    NSParameterAssert(function);

    if ( (self = [self initForPlot:plot]) ) {
        dataSourceFunction = function;
    }
    return self;
}
```

The code compiles fine with Xcode 6.2 but it's giving me the following errors with Xcode 6.3:
`/Users/xxxx/Project/App/Presentation/CorePlot/Source/CPTFunctionDataSource.m:110:5: Using %s directive in NSString which is being passed as a formatting argument to the formatting method`

I have looked up online and have not seen information on the error message.
A temp fix I am using is the following:

```
#undef NSParameterAssert
#define NSParameterAssert(condition)    ({\
do {\
_Pragma("clang diagnostic push")\
_Pragma("clang diagnostic ignored \"-Wcstring-format-directive\"")\
NSAssert((condition), @"Invalid parameter not satisfying: %s", #condition);\
_Pragma("clang diagnostic pop")\
} while(0);\
})
```

There should be a better solution for this though.

Comment: Same problem afte upgrade Xcode.

Comment: No real solution but I worked around it by adding -Wno-cstring-format-directive to WARNING_CFLAGS

Comment: I'm seeing this too. Seems like an Apple SNAFU. Anyone report it to Apple?

Comment: APPLE, WHY? WHY U NO LIKE ME?

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is update your core-plot library to the latest version (that worked for me) BECAUSE:

If you go to Coreplot git repo (https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot/commits/master),

within the commits you can see:

```
Commits on Feb 15, 2015
@eskroch
Fixed Xcode 6.3 beta build warnings.
eskroch authored on Feb 15
```

That means that this problem is already fixed since Feb 15, a long time before this iOS 8.3 release, since the beta version.